# Pass more data into a UISearchController with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uisearchcontroller

I've had a working `UISearchController` for a while now, however I have a slight problem with it.

My Search controller displays a list of train stations from an array. (There's a lot of them so i will cut down the array in the example code below), This all works perfectly fine and I'm happy with it.

The problem is is that I need to pass the train stations GPS coordinates with the station name too. I've been trying to research the best way to do this, but have come up against a wall.

I decided to create another Array which features Station Code, Station, Latitude and Longitude.

Here is the original array:

```
let data = ["Abbey Wood", "Aber", "Abercynon", "Aberdare", "Aberdeen", "Aberdour", "Aberdovey", "Abererch"]
```

Here is the new array:

```
let stations = [Station(code: "ABW", name: "Abbey Wood", latitude: 51.4907705898, longitude: 0.1203255703),
    Station(code: "ABE", name: "Aber", latitude: 51.5749606879, longitude: -3.2298389345),
    Station(code: "ACY", name: "Abercynon", latitude: 51.6447060012, longitude: -3.3270007535),
    Station(code: "ABA", name: "Aberdare", latitude: 51.715057473, longitude: -3.4430991465),
    Station(code: "ABD", name: "Aberdeen", latitude: 57.1430482477, longitude: -2.0974804963),
    Station(code: "AUR", name: "Aberdour", latitude: 56.0545804403, longitude: -3.3005564433),
    Station(code: "AVY", name: "Aberdovey", latitude: 52.543972227, longitude: -4.0570808351),
    Station(code: "ABH", name: "Abererch", latitude: 52.8986004612, longitude: -4.3741959548)]
```

I also wrote this to go with the new array:

```
class Station {

    var code = ""
    var name = ""
    var latitude = 0.0
    var longitude = 0.0

    init(code: String, name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}
```

The problem is is that I am having trouble implementing this into the `UISearchController`.

This is the original code altogether

```
    var filteredData: [String]!

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        filteredData = data

        // Initializing with searchResultsController set to nil means that
        // searchController will use this view controller to display the search results
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        // If we are using this same view controller to present the results
        // dimming it out wouldn't make sense.  Should set probably only set
        // this to yes if using another controller to display the search results.
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        // Sets this view controller as presenting view controller for the search interface
        definesPresentationContext = true

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        //        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

        selectedText = filteredData![indexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToSet", sender: self)
        println("you pressed \(selectedText)")
        println(indexPath.row)

    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text

        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
            return dataString.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

Whatever I try and do now I can't get the station name to pass into tableview,

Am i going about this all wrong, or am i on the right track but just doing something stupid?

Comment: I have some question about your code. You set 'filteredData' variable to 'data' variable, but your new array with Station objects has name 'stations', is it a mistake? And I think, that you should write filteredData![indexPath.row].name to get name of station instead of just filteredData![indexPath.row] (in cellForRowAtIndexPath function)

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying i'm afraid. I know I set `filteredData` to `Data` Its not a mistake, I was going to create another called `var filtered stations = stations` however that throws up an error, but if that had worked in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i would've changed `filteredData` to `filteredStations`. Plus what you said said about my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because you wrote the same thing before and after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and wrote this peace of code. I used only `UITableView` and `UISearchBar` just to keep code clean. I updated function for filtering your array with `Station` objects (`searchBar(_:textDidChange:)`, you should use this part of code in your `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` function).

Everything works fine for me now.

```
class Station {

    var code = ""
    var name = ""
    var latitude = 0.0
    var longitude = 0.0

    init(code: String, name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var filteredData = [Station]()

    let stations = [Station(code: "ABW", name: "Abbey Wood", latitude: 51.4907705898, longitude: 0.1203255703),
        Station(code: "ABE", name: "Aber", latitude: 51.5749606879, longitude: -3.2298389345),
        Station(code: "ACY", name: "Abercynon", latitude: 51.6447060012, longitude: -3.3270007535),
        Station(code: "ABA", name: "Aberdare", latitude: 51.715057473, longitude: -3.4430991465),
        Station(code: "ABD", name: "Aberdeen", latitude: 57.1430482477, longitude: -2.0974804963),
        Station(code: "AUR", name: "Aberdour", latitude: 56.0545804403, longitude: -3.3005564433),
        Station(code: "AVY", name: "Aberdovey", latitude: 52.543972227, longitude: -4.0570808351),
        Station(code: "ABH", name: "Abererch", latitude: 52.8986004612, longitude: -4.3741959548)];


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filteredData = stations
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell") as! UITableViewCell
        // Set name of station to textLabel
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].name 
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var selectedText = filteredData[indexPath.row].name
        println("you pressed \(selectedText)")
        println(indexPath.row)

    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        //Filter through Station objects
        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? stations : stations.filter({(station: Station) -> Bool in
            return station.name.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it needed a set fresh of eyes, to complete your answer i then made `didSelectRow` function look like this `selectedText = filteredData[indexPath.row].name
        alertLat = filteredData[indexPath.row].latitude
        alertLon = filteredData[indexPath.row].longitude
        
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToSet", sender: self)
        println("you're destination is \(selectedText)")
        println("you're destination latitude is \(alertLat)")
        println("you're destination longitude is \(alertLon)")`